# How to create a Spark-SQL dataframe from JSON file where data and schema are both listed

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("PySpark").setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

file = sqlContext.read.json(json_file_path)
file.show()
```

Outputs:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                data|              schema|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|[[The battery is ...|[[[index, integer...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

How do I extract the data using my own created schema.  My schema code is:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StructField, StructType, StringType, IntegerType
schema = StructType([
    StructField('index', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('content', StringType(), True),
    StructField('label', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('label_1', StringType(), True ),
    StructField('label_2', StringType(), True ),
    StructField('label_3', IntegerType(), True ),
    StructField('label_4', IntegerType(), True )])
```

I have tried:

```
file.withColumn("data", from_json("data", schema))\
    .show()
```

But I receive the following error:

```
 cannot resolve 'from_json(`data`)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type, however, '`data`' is of array<struct<content:string,index:bigint,label:bigint,label_1:string,label_2:string,label_3:double,label_4:timestamp>> type.;;
```

Comment: can you put proper sample data input and output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `read` method already recognized the schema in the back.

Try running `file.printSchema()` and it should show more-less the schema that you want.

The way unpack the `data` is to run:

```
file = file.select(explode("data").as("exploded_data"))
```

If you want, you can take it to next level with:

```
file.select(file.col("exploded_data.*"))
```

This will flatten out the schema.

Disclaimer: This is scala code, python might need tiny adjustments

Comment: Yes that worked.  It did require a little bit of adjutments to fit Python: file.select(F.explode(file.data).alias('file')).select('file.*')

Comment: Glad it worked! Please don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you. :)

Comment: Got it! Thanks again